# Component layout not rendered in ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble adding a `Component` dynamically to a `ContainerView`. See this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/7n2hz/

The component root element is placed in the container, but the layout associated with the component is not rendered.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('IndexView inserted');
        var container = this.get('container');
        container.pushObject(Ember.TextField.create());
        container.pushObject(App.MyComponent.create());
    }
});

App.MyContainer = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('MyContainer inserted');
    }
});

App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['my-component'],
    //template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<p>Compiled directly</p>'),
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('MyComponent inserted');
    }
});
```

If I uncomment the `template` property, it does render that content properly. I also insert the component directly into the index view, where it renders properly (though the classNames are not added in this case).

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>Render component directly:</h2>
    {{my-component}}
    <hr/>
    <h2>Add component to container:</h2>
    {{view App.MyContainer viewName="container"}}
</script>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-component">
    <b>My component</b>
</script>
```

I've tried messing around with `Ember.run`, but no luck so far. Is `didInsertElement` the wrong hook for `pushObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should fix your problem. See the layoutName property.

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['my-component'],
    layoutName: 'components/my-component',
    didInsertElement: function() {
        console.log('MyComponent inserted');
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can you show me a working jsfiddle? I get `my-component` (the text of the string passed to `compile` rather than `<b>My component</b>`, which is what is defined in the template. I'm just surprised that the template renders differently in the context of a ContainerView than in a normal View.

Comment: I changed my answer a little bit. A working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7n2hz/6/

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the placement of the component prevents it  from being auto-bound to a layout?